# tree view multi select dropdown in bootstrap 4 in angular 9

Tags: treeview, dropdown, multi-select, angular9

I am looking for tree view multi select dropdown in bootstrap 4, I found it in bootstrap 3.3.7, below is link for bootstrap 3.x
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-tree-select

I also try to use some other but nothing work, if any one have working model please send me.

Below are other options I tried

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-treeview(this is giving fatal error of "selection", when I checked on google I found, this is also not support angular 9)